Can we make a t-test manually to each student or should I take all the students before the intervention and after?
I have an action research and I should test the grades of student before and after the intervention, my study is based on only 6 students with Adhd. I weant to do a t-test to see if the results is significantly positive. I have 5 tests: one before, three in the intervention and one after. How can I do the t-test?

A t-test compares two means. You could do a one-sided paired t-test on the first and last measure but a) This throws away a lot of information and b) With only 6 people, a difference would have to be huge to be significant.
I would recommend just presenting the data and using it to suggest further research.
The best analysis would probably be a multilevel model, but that may be beyond what you have learned.
